# Windows 10: How to list files that doesn't have a file with same name but with different extension?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

I have a music repository that contain mostly mp3 files. I used Minilyrics to download .lrc files for each mp3, so most mp3 files have a corresponding lyrics file with the same name but has .lrc extension in the same folder.

Now I need to list **mp3 files** that doesn't have lyrics. Is there a way to do this in PowerShell or command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below PowerShell will list the the full path name of any `.mp3` files **that do not have any matching `.lrc` files in the same directory with the same base file name**.

Just change the `$pth =` to be the full path to the starting folder which the `.mp3` files reside. This solution will recursively traverse the `$pth` folder for all `.mp3` files in any subfolders too.

### PowerShell

```
$pth = "C:\MP3\Folder\Location";
Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -Include "*.mp3" | % { Process { 
    If ( ! ( Test-Path "$((Split-Path $_.FullName -Resolve))\$($_.BaseName).lrc" ) ) 
    { $_.FullName };
    }};
```

#### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Test-Path](https://ss64.com/ps/test-path.html)
- [Split-Path](https://ss64.com/ps/split-path.html)

Comment: tested and worked on my PC

Comment: Better IMO: `Get-ChildItem -Path $pth -Recurse -Include "*.mp3"
  | ? {(! ( Test-Path "$((Split-Path $_.FullName -Resolve))\$($_.BaseName).lrc" ) ) }
  | Format-Table;`

Comment: Perhaps that's a preference but `foreach-object` with conditional `If` performs better than `where-object` so that's out of habit with the way I write code. Same with the `process {}` too. I'm not sure of the scale so I typically just go with what performs best out of habit. You can use `Measure-Command {}` to compare the time of the operations to confirm.

Comment: Won't you get better performance if you let the FileSytem Provider do the filtering? `Get-ChildItem -Path $pth\*.mp3`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I typically see the `Process { If() {} }` conditional perform better than any `where-object {}` filtering per `Measure-Command {}` results. I suppose it's a case by case basis based on the file scale perhaps. What's always more easily readable is not always most performant. The good thing is, the OP has a choice and more than one way to do the task via PowerShell. Which way performs better may vary but easy enough to confirm and adjust per environment if performance if of importance. I'm a creature of habit I guess... We're getting deep here... lol

Comment: Or are you saying `$path -Recurse -Include "*.mp3"` isn't as good as `$pth\*.mp3 -Recurse` without `-Include` parameter that way as that may be a good point. I'll have to test that out to see which performs better if that's what you're saying here. My comment was regarding the `where-object` filtering in particular.

Comment: Right. I read that the `-Path` and `-Filter` are passed to the File System Provider and thus faster than `-Include` or `-Exclude`. Most likely trivial in this case, but good to keep in mind when optimizing.

Comment: I appreciate that tip @KeithMiller... I'll definitely will be keeping this in mind moving forward and putting it to the `measure-command` test. I'll keep my eyes peeled for the reading if I run across it too. I probably should read the MS post for `get-childitem` with detail one day rather than so much pecking at it...

Comment: Just did a quick test with the three methods and it seems the best performant on a small but consistent scale was using the `$pth -Recurse -filter "*.mp3"` even over the ``$pth\*.mp3 -Recurse`` way it performed better more consistently quicker. I read on SS64 there is a bug with the `-filter` parameter when using `-LiteralPath` parameter which I actually use a lot so maybe I ran into this bug before and that's why it didn't stick. Good to know regardless though for optimizing when it can be used and that's important.

Comment: That's interesting because I also thought I also read somewhere that `Path` and `Filter` parameters were essentially concatenated by the Provider. Oh well, there should always be a little mysery under the hood! :D

Comment: Also, does `-Resolve` with `Split-Path` serve any purpose in a case like this? Since the path you're spliting is the `FullName` of a `FIleInfo` object, isn't it already "guaranteed" to be valid?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Python installed on your computer, you could just paste this code into a file called `songlister.py` and put it in the same folder as all the `.mp3` and `.lrc` files, then just run it from the command line like this:

```
python songlister.py
```

and it will list all the names of the songs that don't have a `.lrc` file!

Here's the code:

```python
import glob,re

# These give the lists of all the .mp3 and .lrc files in your current folder and sub folders
mp3_files = glob.glob("/**/*.mp3", recursive=True)
lyric_files = glob.glob("/**/*.lrc", recursive=True)

# For every .mp3 file, check if it has a matching .lrc file.
for i in mp3_files:
    music_name = re.search(".*\.mp3$", i).group().replace('.mp3', '')
    match = False
    for s in lyric_files:
        lyric_name = re.search(".*\.lrc$", s).group().replace('.lrc', '')

# If it does NOT have a .lrc file, then list the name of the file.
        if lyric_name == music_name: 
            match = True
            break
    if not match:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Python is very good idea. I didn't consider Python because I don't know Python. I tried this script. It has 1 problem: If there are 100 lrc files in this folder, it will print the same mp3 filename 100 times if it doesn't have a lyrics file or 99 times if does have one. So I improved the code, and added recursion for sub folders. Please tell me if there are any mistakes as I was coding while googling. Code is too long to fit in a comment, so I edited the code in your answer

Comment: ah, thank you! sorry, i just wrote this in like 2 minutes and didn't think more carefully about that potential issue. as for adding recursion, i just assumed everything was in the parent folder, so i didn't add that, but i appreciate the clarification! i'll review the edits and check it out.

Comment: Looks good to me  added those changes, just changed one thing for better syntax.

Comment: You could use Python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It has `glob`, `exists` and `with_suffix`. For each mp3, you could simply check if the corresponding `lrc` file exists, which would simplify your code very much. I cannot test under Windows right now, but it's possible that `glob.glob("/**/*.mp3")` list every mp3 file on your computer, not just the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the low-tech approach I would use. From a command prompt, do `dir /b|sort > list.txt`. This produces the list of files in the file list.txt, ordered alphabetically.

Then open the file in Excel, or Google Sheets. The list of file names will appear in column A. In cell B1, enter `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))`, and then copy this to all of column B (or, more properly, for as long as the file names exist); concretely, while on cell B1 press `Ctrl-C`, then select the whole column, and press `Ctrl-V`. This produces the list of extensions on column B. Then, on cell C1, enter `=IF(B1=B2,A1,"")`, and again copy over the whole column. Now on column C you have the list of files with no lrc file (properly, this would also show a file with lrc but no mp3 file).